# Getting error UserSession.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext): no suitable method found to override in mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

I have created one demo in mvc 5 and now I need to create one custom filter in my demo. I have used mvc 5.
I need to check every time what method is execute like is a ajax call or action method call in mvc.

Here I have write like this code in my class.

```
 public class UserSession
 : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
        if (ApplicationSession.IsSessionAlive)
            return;

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var ajaxRedirectTarget = new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "FailAuthenticationAjax" }, { "controller", "Home" } };
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(ajaxRedirectTarget);
        }
        else
        {
            var redirectTarget = new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Login" }, { "controller", "Account" } };
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTarget);
        }
    }
}
```

but I got error like this **UserSession.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext): no suitable method found to override**

After I have put this class on my controller like this.

```
[UserSession]
public class DashboardController
{

}
```

any one know how to fixed this issue in mvc 5?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834899(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have click on System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute and in the meta data file my action method like this show
        public virtual void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext);

Comment: That's correct. That's the method you should override. You are overriding method with different signature

Comment: DashboardController is a web api controller or a mvc controller?